# Динамическая цена торгового предложения в Битрикс ЦМС

Tags: php, cms, битрикс

CMS Bitrix. Столкнулся с проблемой, цена товара зависит от нескольких характеристик, в том числе от характеристики "Толщина листа", которая варьируется по разному в зависимости от товара, в рамках примера, пусть это будет от 200 до 2000. Пользователь вводит это число в инпут и исходя из выбранных характеристик товару высчитывается стоимость. Эта характеристика(толщина листа) и делает невозможным реализацию просто через торговые предложения. По сути, в каждом товаре находится калькулятор его цены. Как такое лучше всего реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

модифицируйте шаблоны вывода каталога. добавьте поле инпут с ограничением на минимально и максимально возможное значение. И модифицируйте расчет цены в зависимости от значения этого инпута. По дефолту у Вас в инпуте должно быть какое-то значение.
Но если память мне не изменяет, то согласно общедоступной в курсах информации, можно создавать торговые предложения влияющие на цену.
Но это при учете, что у Вас фиксированный набор значений. Если да, то обратитесь к докментации и форуме.
Просмотрите курсы: [Администратор.Бизнес](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42), а также [Администратор. Базовый](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35) и [Администратор.Модули](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=41). 
Если не поможет, то можете обратится к [Marketplace](http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru) может быть кто-то уже реализовал подобное.